# Form Validations and Stripe Checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Just trying to validate some custom parameters passed before Stripe Checkout

[image]

```
<%= form_tag charges_path, class: 'stripeform' do %>
  <input type="text" spellcheck="off" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" class="name" required>
  <input type="text" spellcheck="off" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" class="name" required>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" required> I accept the <u>Terms and Conditions</u>
  <button id="submitter">
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
        data-label="Pay"
        data-panel-label="Pay"</script>
  </button>
<% end %>
```

No validations occur when I click on the Stripe button.

The validations only occur when I click on the button id="submitter" that is behind it:

[image]

I do not want the button behind it. I want the Stripe button to validate the fields. How to do this, given that the Stripe's button's HTML is generated?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do.

Do you want to perform validation of your custom fields, then if validation passes, *then* display the Stripe Checkout popup? If that's the case, you probably want to make a custom checkout flow, like in:

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Or, are you trying to display the Stripe Checkout popup *before* validation is done on the custom fields, and perform this validation when the user clicks on the 'Pay now' button in the popup? This sort of thing isn't really supported by checkout. If this is what you are trying to do, you will probably want to write a completely custom checkout form, like in:

https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms

Then, you can have whatever checkout flow you need to have, although this may be a bit more involved than just using the pre-built checkout.